# service "phpfpm" is not running container #1

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm trying to setup magento 2 on my work Macbook Pro M1 to test and get familiar to magento platform. I'm following https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento to install it with docker.

However, I'm facing the following errors after entering Composer authentications.

[image]

Did I miss out anything?

Answer (score 0):

I too got this error. After I increased the RAM to 6GB in the docker settings, my installation moved forward.