# Unable to access magento on local machine

Tags: magento2, base-url

I'm installing a magento on my local ubuntu vm to play around with it. I have successfully installed it but accessing it with local domain is not working.

I have added xyz.com as local domain in the ngix config as below.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {
server_name xyz.com;
listen 80;
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento;
set $MAGE_MODE developer; # or production

access_log /var/log/nginx/magento-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/magento-error.log;

include /var/www/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

And in the magento installation, I hav set the base-url to xyz.com as well.

```
sudo -u www-data bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://xyz.com --db-host=localhost --db-name=mydb --db-user=myuser --db-password=mypass --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=http://localhost --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 --elasticsearch-timeout=15 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0
```

But when I try to access xyz.com from the browser, instead of my magento website, it goes to the actual xyz.com from the internet.

Did I miss anything to be configured?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance replaced images with texts now.

Answer (score 1):

To point `xyz.com` to your local machine, you need to add a config to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 xyz.com
```

Comment: I did that but still going to the internet.

Comment: @YeMyatAung You might need to flush your DNS records cache

Comment: @YeMyatAung I noticed that you attempted to set up Magento on your local environment by using docker-magento. Someone has provided a solution in your post, did you check it out?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368238/service-phpfpm-is-not-running-container-1. I highly recommend using that docker configuration as it significantly saves time in development and setting up the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the xyz.com to localhost and I can now access it.